# DIV not working in Firefox but working in IE8

Tags: html, extjs

I am using Ext JS to render an itemselector in itemselector DIV a panel in editor-grid DIV and a form in editor-grid1 DIV. What i am trying to do is, initially the editor-grid1 is visible and when the user submits the form in editor-grid1 then the panel is visible and when the user clicks the result of the panel the item selector is visible. Its perfect in IE8 but editor-grid/panel DIV & itemselector DIV is not visible in firefox even after submitting the form.

Here is my html

```
<body>
<div id="loading-mask"></div>
<div id="loading">
  <div class="loading-indicator">
   <table></table>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="editor-grid1" align="center"></div>
<div id="editor-grid" style="LEFT: 17px; top: 135px; POSITION: absolute;"></div>
 <div id="itemselector" class="demo-ct" style="LEFT: 472px; top: 135px; POSITION:absolute; display:'none';"></div>
</body>
```